# Saving ID from CSV and associate to a response from tRestClient

Tags: java, api, csv, etl, talend

I just started my adventure with Talend Open Studio,

*I am having trouble figuring out how to solve a problem I am encountering.*

I have a `tFileInputDelimited` as input with a two-column schema (**name** and **id**), on which I am iterating with `tFlowToIterate`, saving these two variables together using `tFixedFlowInput` in order to use the **name** variable as a query parameter on `tRestClient`, and then extracting the response with `tExtractJSONField`.

I would like to keep the id variable to associate it with each response, but since the id variable is not a valid parameter for the query, I am looking for a way to add it during my mapping in `tExtractJSONField`.

*Any help will be appreciated*

[image]

[image]

Find a solution to save variable and add to the corresponding response

Comment: So if I’m understanding you correctly, you want to refer to the ID field later on in the job but you’ve lost any reference because it existed further back and you don’t have access to it now, correct?

Comment: Yes, kind of. With tRestClient, there are three schemas:

1- for the entry (id, name)
2 -for the response (statusCode, body, string)
3- for the error (errorCode, errorMessage)

I can only have the response on one side and the error on the other. tExtractJSONField maps data based on the string inside the response schema. I tried to add a manually id column with the reference row5.id but it doesn't work because the mapping is based on the string.

Comment: So have a `tMap` after it that adds the ID.  No?  Does that allow you to reference `row5.id`?  If not, let me know because I'll have an answer for you.

Comment: **YES**,  it's work perfectly ! thank you for helping me to wrap my problem